# need to refresh a uilabel programmatically in a tableview when slider is changed

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uislider

i have a tableview in which there is a uislider at section 2 and row 3 and a label in the same place,i need to change the value of uilabel as the uislider is changed . i have given method for uislider like

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and   for uislider i have given

```
-(void)sliderAction:(UISlider*)sender;

{   
    NSLog(@"%f",[sender value]);

    MlifetimeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[sender value]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

in nslog i am getting a continous stream of values but in the label......things are not getting refreshed properly........help

Comment: You shouldn't need to reload the table at all. The label should just change like any other label. Reloading is if you wantto update the cells themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to reload the whole table as you know the row and section of the cell that you have to change just try this code in the selector method.

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2]] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I am assuming that you are counting the row and section from 0 index not 1 otherwise use

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to update the label on the main thread.
try something like

> NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[sender value]];
>
> [MlifetimeLabel performSelectorOnMainThread : @
>   selector(setText : ) withObject:str
>   waitUntilDone:YES];